# Samsung Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile, android-camera-intent

let me address my issue here.
i'm using an `Intent` to grab an image from the camera file by passing a file along the `Intent` to return it, however in my tests in the Samsung Galaxy S5, if the image was taken normally the image will return, but lets say if Samsung tries to handle low light and do its "so called hard working" the application will crash. i'v tried storing the `fileName` in `onSaveInstanceState` and retreiving it in `onRestoreInstanceState` this prevent the application from crashing, but however it recreates my `Activity` which below it there is another `Activity` which has `BroadcastReceiver` that is been destroyed along when the `Activity` recreated, is there any workaround to tell Samsung to take the image without its crappy features to prevent this scenario from happening?
**Edit**
with test with only sending the `Intent` without passing a `Uri` file with it, it still if it handles low lights, the application will crash.

Comment: Will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248265/camera-intent-not-working-with-samsung-galaxy-s3/15287164#15287164) help?

Comment: @Skynet nope, it doesn't, the problem as i described that the image returns fine, only it crashes the App when Samsung tries to handle low lights. i'm trying to prevent this from recreating my Activity.

Comment: Please post the manifest declaration of this particular activity.

Comment: @Skynet `android:name=".activities.PhotoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="user"`

Comment: Seems proper, can you use the [Debug](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) class to pin point where exactly does it crash?

Comment: there is no such way you can tell what cause the application to crash, basically when it returns to the `onActivityResult` it crashes the application. for example, the file i passed along the intent returns null if the image taken with handling low light, even if i checked against the file or the uri, the application still going to recreate it due to cause of samsung return result

Comment: Samsung my friend, is crazy!

Comment: @Skynet tell me about it :) .. you have all of your application works on Samsung and then when you try to test it on different phone, boom. your application crashes.

Comment: did you find a way to solve this? i think i am having the exact same issue, my app is recreated... i dont mind if the image is not available yet, i just want my app not to be recreated...

Comment: Nope, no such way unless if u create an activity where it only handles the camera intent so instead of opening intent for camera u open the other activity which.opens the camera intent this will.result in that activity recreation not ur main activity.

Comment: Having the same issue. this is the dumbest bug I have ever came across. :/

Answer (score 1):

While developing our Cordova app on Android on a Samsung S5, I've noticed the same issues – in regular mode, the Samsung camera app appears to use less memory, so the Android garbage collector doesn't kill our app. However, in the low-light mode you're describing, the Android garbage collector kills our app in the background.

The Cordova camera plugin doesn't support the Android lifecycle, so I've had to [fork it](https://github.com/jfrumar/cordova-plugin-camera), and store the imageUri (and some other settings) to a Preference in order to retrieve it again once the app restarts.

I think you'll need to put a `Debug.waitForDebugger()` statement in your `onActivityResult` method, so that when your app restarts you can connect the debugger and step through your code that processes the result. My guess is that you're referencing a variable that isn't available because of the loss of state.